# Ajax data isn't being received by php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Hello overflowers!**

I can't seem to manage to send my ajax data over to my php page correctly, it has worked perfectly fine before but now it is not working.

I'm getting the correct data via `console.log` but on my php page i'm getting `Undefined index` error.

**Jquery**

```
  var task_takers_pre = [];
  var task_takers = [];
  var i = 1;

  $(".new-task-takers ul.select_takers li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      if($(this).find('.fa').length > 0){
        $(this).find('.fa').remove();
        i -= 1;
        var removeItem = $(this).data("id");
        task_takers_pre.remove(removeItem);
        console.log(task_takers_pre);
      }else{
        $('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>').insertBefore($(this).find("div"));
        i += 1;
        task_takers_pre[i] = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(task_takers_pre);
      }

      $.each(task_takers_pre, function (index, value) {
        if ($.inArray(value, task_takers) == -1) {
          task_takers.push(index, value);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $("#new-task").on('submit', function(){
    console.log(task_takers_pre);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '',
      cache: false,
      data: {task_takers_pre : task_takers_pre },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data)
      }
    });
  });
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['task_submit'])){
    $task_takers = $_POST['task_takers_pre'][0];
    var_dump($task_takers);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

**jQuery**

```
var task_takers_pre = [];
  var task_takers = [];
  var i = 1;

  $(".new-task-takers ul.select_takers li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).each(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
      if($(this).find('.fa').length > 0){
        $(this).find('.fa').remove();
        i -= 1;
        var removeItem = $(this).data("id");
        task_takers_pre.remove(removeItem);
        console.log(task_takers_pre);
      }else{
        $('<i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>').insertBefore($(this).find("div"));
        i += 1;
        task_takers_pre[i] = $(this).data("id");
        console.log(task_takers_pre);
      }

      $.each(task_takers_pre, function (index, value) {
        if ($.inArray(value, task_takers) == -1) {
          task_takers.push(index, value);
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $(".assign").on('click', function(){
      console.log(task_takers_pre);
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: './core/includes/new_task.php',
        cache: false,
        data: {task_takers_pre : task_takers_pre},
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data)
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '',
        cache: false,
        data: {'task_takers_pre' : task_takers_pre},
        success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data)
        }
      });
    });
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['task_takers_pre'][0])){
    $task_takers = $_POST['task_takers_pre'][0]; // Just for testing
    var_dump($task_takers);                      // Just for testing
}

if(isset($_POST['task_takers_pre'])){
    $task_takers2 = $_POST['task_takers_pre']; // Just for testing
    var_dump($task_takers2);                      // Just for testing
}
```

Comment: Your Ajax has no url, are you supplying it elsewhere?

Comment: Also, you are not posting task_submit, so your test for isset($_POST['task_submit']) will always be false.

Comment: I have never used any url before and it has always worked. @Blinkydamo

Comment: How do you mean? The whole code is with inputs and selects, and the task_submit is a button you click. @TimBrownlaw

Comment: Your javascript posts only `data: {task_takers_pre : task_takers_pre },` and `task_submit` is not in that array

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/G9YseKw.png @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is use the same PHP code to handle the Button Press from the Form AND the AJAX Call. Don't!

(note: This answer is Only based upon the code that has been provided and what is trying to achieved with this code.)

So your current PHP is, which I am guessing is what you call when you click the submit button... In that case $_POST['task_takers_pre'] will not exist as you are generating that from the JS and sending it in the AJAX Call.

Write a separate AJAX Call.

You need to create a separate file to handle your AJAX calls and have it perform what duties it needs to perform.

```
// This is just for testing my AJAX Call
    public function ajax_post(){
      if(isset($_POST['task_takers_pre'])){
        $task_takers = $_POST['task_takers_pre'][0]; // Just for testing
        var_dump($task_takers);                      // Just for testing
        die();
      }
      else {
      // Illegal access/entry do something...
      echo 'Error - I had better check what I am posting.';
      die();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Alright, I'm going to update my question with a new code. The thing is the post isn't being received anyways.

Comment: I have altered my answer a little (it was answered thinking you were using codeigniter - my bad).

Comment: Just to test that you are hitting the correct URL, just put a die('You found me!'); on the very first line of your file new_task.php. If that dont work, try putting in the Full URL in.

Comment: Alright I managed to get the `You found me!` but the data on success `console.log` from the jQuery isn't posting it back.

Comment: Ok so now if you put this before the die() we had added (remove the message from inside it so its just die(); ) ... echo json_encode(['stuff'=>'This worked'])'. So now we are forcing an echo back of some hardcoded data. See what that does.

Comment: Brilliant! So what if we now change the echo....  to send back $_POST, ie echo json_encode(['The Post is'=>$_POST]);

Comment: Alright this time I'm getting it back but it's an empty value added `{"The Post is":["","2","3"]}`

Comment: You're amazing, I managed to read the data to the php page thanks to you!

Comment: You are very welcome... it was more a lesson in what I call, sleepy debug methods :) when it all seems too hard to work out... So I am pleased you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

If you juse want to send some data in the AJAX Call when you click the submit button,you could return false to prevent form submission in the submit event.

```js
$("#new-task").on("submit", function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    cache: false,
    data: {task_submit:1, task_takers_pre: task_takers_pre},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```